# Unable to connect to BSC testnet with web3.js

Tags: web3js, bsc, binance

From this [tutorial](https://medium.com/spartanprotocol/how-to-connect-metamask-to-bsc-testnet-7d89c111ab2), I learned the RPC URL for BSC Testnet is https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545, but when I use it with web3.js like:

```
const web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545');
```

I get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream'`. I am coding for a frontend, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to node you need to select the provider type, examples - **HttpProvider**, **WebsocketProvider**, and **IpcProvider** . In your case just change:

```
new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545');
```

To:

```
new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545'))
```

Comment: I was following [this tutorial](https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/web3-js-intro) which says `const web3 = new Web3(rpcURL)` should work. I tried your proposed solution and got the same error in my original post.

Comment: Something is definelly wrong at your side. Check my sample code at https://pastebin.com/Mktuz8qA , I'm using latest web3 version ```1.6.1``` and I added ```web3.eth.getBlockNumber``` function just to see if my ```web3``` instance is correctly reading the blockchain data and it is.

Comment: Could it be that I am trying to do this in a browser? That is where I would like to fetch the blockchain data.

Comment: Yes, this is the issue. You can use this tool https://browserify.org/ which compiles all the javascript code which is not supported by the browsers into a "bundled" js file.